# Read/Write IPTC information on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iptc

I'm developing an application on the iPhone and i want to know how to read/write IPTC informations in pictures through the iPhone, there is a library or code example to do it?

Comment: information that is saved in pictures and contains like the author, tags, where the pictures was taken and other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExifTool by Phil Harvey handles IPTC metadata.
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Also CoreGraphics supports IPTC metadata.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005103

Comment: what i want is to change the information from the iPhone application that i'm developing.

Comment: ExifTool is a Pearl library that reads and writes metadata including IPTC data. It has been used on the Mac. I assume it can be used on the iPhone also.